# Why lmerTest does not give p-values to some models?

Tags: r, lmer

I ran the model:

```
lmer11 <- lmerTest::lmer(duration ~ (1|piece) + (1+color|speaker) + group*color*sex, data=data1.frame, REML=FALSE, na.action=na.omit)
```

The output is similar to lmer. I do not understand as I run the same syntax structure of other models, and it works fine. Do you have any idea why lmerTest does not give me p-values for this model?

Answer (score 2):

By default in lmerTest if some error occurs then the output from lme4 is provided. So I guess some computational error has occurred - probably the reason lies in the non-positive definite asymptotic variance-covariance matrix for this model - a reproducible example together with the sessionInfo() would really help!

Comment: Hi Alexandra, lmerTest also gives me this: 
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "df",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent  / I have no idea what this mean. Do you have any idea?